Header of NestedScrollView not pushing body content down
I have some expandable cards in the header of my NestedScrollView. When i toggle the cards i expect it to push the ListView in the body of the NestedScrollView up and down, but it remains static. This strange behaviour happens only when i set container with a fixed height as shown in my code. How can i ensure that the content always pushes up an down ehrn i expand and clise my cards?
return NestedScrollView(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                      return [
                        SliverToBoxAdapter(
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.h),
                                color: GrayColors.grayG10,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  child: PageView.builder(
                                    controller: _pageController,
                                    itemCount: events.length,
                                    onPageChanged: (index) {
                                      updateIndex(index);
                                    },
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return _buildPage(
                                        size,
                                        events.whereType<TrackerEvent>().toList(),
                                        index,
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                left: 8,
                                bottom: 0,
                                top: 0,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _pageController.previousPage(
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 15,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.33),
                                    child: Assets.images.svg.navLeft.svg(
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                        GrayColors.grayG50,
                                        BlendMode.srcIn,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                right: 8,
                                bottom: 0,
                                top: 0,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _pageController.nextPage(
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 15,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.33),
                                    child: Assets.images.svg.navRight.svg(
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                        GrayColors.grayG50,
                                        BlendMode.srcIn,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ];
                    },
                    body: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h),
                      itemCount: events.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return TrackerItem(
                          events[index],
                          onTap: () {
                            final controller =
                                ref.read(routineHistoryControllerProvider.notifier);
                            controller.navigateToRoutine(events[index]);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );

